# Call to Dropbox API Client.Files.DownloadAsync does not return metadata when call from an instance of TimerCallback

Tags: ios, xamarin, asynchronous, dropbox-api, dotnet-httpclient

I’ve got a mobile crossplatform Xamarin.Forms project in which I try to download a file from a Dropbox repository at startup. It’s a tiny json file of less than 50kB. The code operating the Dropbox API call is shared between my Android and my iOS projects, and my Android implementation works as intended. It’s a `Task` method which I’ll call the `downloader` here for convenience.

**UPDATED:** With the iOS version, I can download the file successfully only when calling my `downloader`’s launcher (which is a also Task) directly from the `BackgroundSynchronizer.Launch()` method of my only `AppDelegate`, but not when delegating this call using a timer to call my `downloader` through a `TimerCallback` which calls an `EventHandler` at recurring times.

I can’t figure out why.

The `downloader`:

```
public class DropboxStorage : IDistantStoreService
{
    private string oAuthToken;
    private DropboxClientConfig clientConfig; 
    private Logger logger = new Logger
        (DependencyService.Get<ILoggingBackend>());

    public DropboxStorage()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
        clientConfig = new DropboxClientConfig
        {
            HttpClient = httpClient
        };
    }

    public async Task SetConnection()
    {
        await GetAccessToken();
    }

    public async Task<Stream> DownloadFile(string distantUri)
    {
        logger.Info("Dropbox downloader called.");
        try
        {
            await SetConnection();
            using var client = new DropboxClient(oAuthToken, clientConfig);
            var downloadArg = new DownloadArg(distantUri);
            var metadata = await client.Files.DownloadAsync(downloadArg);
            var stream = metadata?.GetContentAsStreamAsync();
            return await stream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**UPDATED:** The `AppDelegate`:

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace Izibio.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {

        private BackgroundSynchronizer synchronizer = new BackgroundSynchronizer();
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            synchronizer.Launch();
            base.OnActivated(uiApplication);
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The intermediary class (which embeds the DownloadProducts function):

```
public static class DropboxNetworkRequests
    {
        public static async Task DownloadProducts(IDistantStoreService distantStorage,
            IStoreService localStorage)
        {
            try
            {
                var productsFileName = Path.GetFileName(Globals.ProductsFile);
                var storeDirectory = $"/{Globals.StoreId}_products";
                var productsFileUri = Path.Combine(storeDirectory, productsFileName);
                var stream = await distantStorage.DownloadFile(productsFileUri);
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    await localStorage.Save(stream, productsFileUri);
                }
                else
                {
                    var logger = GetLogger();
                    logger.Info($"No file with the uri ’{productsFileUri}’ could " +
                        $"have been downloaded.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = GetLogger();
                logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }

        private static Logger GetLogger()
        {
            var loggingBackend = DependencyService.Get<ILoggingBackend>();
            return new Logger(loggingBackend);
        }

    }
```

**UPDATED:** And the failing launcher class (the commented `TriggerNetworkOperations(this, EventArgs.Empty);`
 in the Launch method succeeds in downloading the file) :

```
public class BackgroundSynchronizer
{
    private bool isDownloadRunning;
    private IDistantStoreService distantStorage;
    private IStoreService localStorage;
    private Timer timer;
    public event EventHandler SynchronizationRequested;

    public BackgroundSynchronizer()
    {
        Forms.Init();
        isDownloadRunning = false;
        distantStorage = DependencyService.Get<IDistantStoreService>();
        localStorage = DependencyService.Get<IStoreService>();
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += TriggerNetworkOperations;
        SynchronizationRequested += TriggerNetworkOperations;
    }

    public void Launch()
    {
        try
        {
            var millisecondsInterval = Globals.AutoDownloadMillisecondsInterval;
            var callback = new TimerCallback(SynchronizationCallback);
            timer = new Timer(callback, this, 0, 0);
            timer.Change(0, millisecondsInterval);
            //TriggerNetworkOperations(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnSynchronizationRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SynchronizationRequested?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    private async void TriggerNetworkOperations(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet) && !isDownloadRunning)
        {
            await DownloadProducts(sender);
        }
    }

    private async void TriggerNetworkOperations(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isDownloadRunning)
        {
            await DownloadProducts(sender);
        }
    }

    private void SynchronizationCallback(object state)
    {
        SynchronizationRequested(state, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private async Task DownloadProducts(object sender)
    {
        var instance = (BackgroundSynchronizer)sender;
        //Anti-reentrance assignments commented for debugging purposes
        //isDownloadRunning = true;
        await DropboxNetworkRequests.DownloadProducts(instance.distantStorage, instance.localStorage);
        //isDownloadRunning = false;
    }
}
```

I set a logging file to record my application behaviour when trying to download.

**EDIT:** Here are the messages I get when calling directly TriggerNetworkOperations from the Launch method:

```
2019-11-12 19:31:57.1758|INFO|xamarinLogger|iZiBio Mobile Launched
2019-11-12 19:31:57.4875|INFO|persistenceLogger|Dropbox downloader called.
2019-11-12 19:31:58.4810|INFO|persistenceLogger|Writing /MAZEDI_products/assortiment.json at /Users/dev3/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5BABB56B-9B42-4653-9D3E-3C60CFFD50A8/data/Containers/Data/Application/D6C517E9-3446-4916-AD8D-565F4C206AF2/Library/assortiment.json
```

**EDIT:** And are those I get when launching through the timer and its callback (with a 10 seconds interval for debugging purposes):

```
2019-11-12 19:34:05.5166|INFO|xamarinLogger|iZiBio Mobile Launched
2019-11-12 19:34:05.8149|INFO|persistenceLogger|Dropbox downloader called.
2019-11-12 19:34:15.8083|INFO|persistenceLogger|Dropbox downloader called.
2019-11-12 19:34:25.8087|INFO|persistenceLogger|Dropbox downloader called.
2019-11-12 19:34:35.8089|INFO|persistenceLogger|Dropbox downloader called.
```

**EDIT:** In this second scenario, the launched task event eventually gets cancelled by the OS:

```
2019-11-13 09:36:29.7359|ERROR|persistenceLogger|System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
  at ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002a5] in /Users/paul/code/paulcbetts/modernhttpclient/src/ModernHttpClient/iOS/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs:139 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncWorker (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0009e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:281 
  at Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler.RequestJsonString (System.String host, System.String routeName, System.String auth, Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler+RouteStyle routeStyle, System.String requestArg, System.IO.Stream body) [0x0030f] in <8d8475f2111a4ae5850a1c1349c08d28>:0 
  at Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler.RequestJsonStringWithRetry (System.String host, System.String routeName, System.String auth, Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler+RouteStyle routeStyle, System.String requestArg, System.IO.Stream body) [0x000f6] in <8d8475f2111a4ae5850a1c1349c08d28>:0 
  at Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler.Dropbox.Api.Stone.ITransport.SendDownloadRequestAsync[TRequest,TResponse,TError] (TRequest request, System.String host, System.String route, System.String auth, Dropbox.Api.Stone.IEncoder`1[T] requestEncoder, Dropbox.Api.Stone.IDecoder`1[T] resposneDecoder, Dropbox.Api.Stone.IDecoder`1[T] errorDecoder) [0x000a5] in <8d8475f2111a4ae5850a1c1349c08d28>:0 
  at Izibio.Persistence.DropboxStorage.DownloadFile (System.String distantUri) [0x00105] in /Users/dev3/Virtual Machines.localized/shared/TRACAVRAC/izibio-mobile/Izibio/Izibio.Persistence/Services/DropboxStorage.cs:44 
2019-11-13 09:36:29.7399|INFO|persistenceLogger|No file with the uri ’/******_products/assortiment.json’ could have been downloaded.
```

I’ll simply add a last observation: when debugging the `DownloadFile` Task from the `BackgroundSynchronizer`, I can reach the call to `client.Files.DowloadAsync`: `var metadata = await client.Files.DownloadAsync(downloadArg);`, but I won’t retrieve any return from this await statement.

Comment: Why is the launched task event eventually gets cancelled by the OS? Can you add a try-catch there to see if there is any exception there.

Comment: You're calling Forms.Init twice, which may be causing issues. You call it in FinishedLaunching, but also in the constructor for BackgroundSynchronizer. Also you are not awaiting TestDownload so any exceptions may be swallowed... always "await" calls to async methods is a best practice. However, I don't see where you are calling DownloadFile, so this is an incomplete sample. Always provide an MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT : there was already a try-catch, but as stated by jgoldberger, the snippet was missing; I included it now, and also the logged error.

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT : I included the snippet you mentionned, but I don’t know how much more code I could realistically copy to make my post a complete MCVE sample, as there are many pieces of codes that I did not even edited coming with the creation of my Xamarin solution. Do you think it’s complete enough like that? The TestDownload is willingly dirty (duplicated call to Forms.Init and no awaiting) as its only purpose is to assess that the underlying code works when called this way from the AppDelegate : the whole function will be deleted as soon as I fix the synchronizer.Launch() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found a way out of this by replacing the .NET timer by the iOS implementation (NSTimer).

My new code for the BackgroundSynchronizer class:

```
    public class BackgroundSynchronizer
    {
        private bool isDownloadRunning;
        private IDistantStoreService distantStorage;
        private IStoreService localStorage;
        private NSTimer timer;
        public event EventHandler SynchronizationRequested;

        public BackgroundSynchronizer()
        {
            Forms.Init();
            isDownloadRunning = false;
            distantStorage = DependencyService.Get<IDistantStoreService>();
            localStorage = DependencyService.Get<IStoreService>();
            Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += TriggerNetworkOperations;
            SynchronizationRequested += TriggerNetworkOperations;
        }

        public void Launch()
        {
            try
            {
                var seconds = Globals.AutoDownloadMillisecondsInterval / 1000;
                var interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds);
                var callback = new Action<NSTimer>(SynchronizationCallback);
                StartTimer(interval, callback);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnSynchronizationRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SynchronizationRequested?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }

        private async void TriggerNetworkOperations(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet) && !isDownloadRunning)
            {
                await DownloadProducts();
            }
        }

        private async void TriggerNetworkOperations(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isDownloadRunning)
            {
                await DownloadProducts();
            }
        }

        private void SynchronizationCallback(object state)
        {
            SynchronizationRequested(state, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private async Task DownloadProducts()
        {
            isDownloadRunning = true;
            await DropboxNetworkRequests.DownloadProducts(distantStorage, localStorage);
            isDownloadRunning = false;
        }

        private void StartTimer(TimeSpan interval, Action<NSTimer> callback)
        {
            timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingTimer(interval, callback);
            NSRunLoop.Main.AddTimer(timer, NSRunLoopMode.Common);   
        }
    }
```

Which produces the following logging lines:

```
2019-11-13 14:00:58.2086|INFO|xamarinLogger|iZiBio Mobile Launched
2019-11-13 14:01:08.5378|INFO|persistenceLogger|Dropbox downloader called.
2019-11-13 14:01:09.5656|INFO|persistenceLogger|Writing /****_products/assortiment.json at /Users/dev3/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/****/data/Containers/Data/Application/****/Library/assortiment.json
2019-11-13 14:01:18.5303|INFO|persistenceLogger|Dropbox downloader called.
2019-11-13 14:01:19.2375|INFO|persistenceLogger|Writing /****_products/assortiment.json at /Users/dev3/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/****/data/Containers/Data/Application/****/Library/assortiment.json
```

But I’m still open to an enlighted explanation of the reason why both timers result in such different behaviours.